# Mysql Query - Joins causing confusion for me in this query

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query that returns results related to items that match a specific category...

There are 3 mysql tables that results to this, `items`, `categories` and `item_categories`.

These i assume are self explanatory, but the latter, is a linking table that links any specific item to any specific category, using a match of id's.

The items table contains one row, with an `id` value of 1.

The categories table is filled with 15 rows, with `id` values of 1-15.

the item_categories table contains one row, the `item_id` value is 1 and the `category_id` value is 5.

This is the mysql query in its php form:

```
$catResultQuery = "
        SELECT i.id, name, price
        FROM items i
        INNER JOIN item_categories
            ON i.id = item_id
        INNER JOIN categories c
            ON category_id = c.id
        WHERE MATCH (c.id)
        AGAINST ('{$_SESSION['input']}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        ORDER BY name
";
```

The session variable has a value of 5, but for some reason, this query displays a 0 result set.

Even when i run the query in php myadmin, it returns 0 rows.

And i am confused, because in my head, the logic behind all of this seems fairly simple, but for some reason i get 0? Does anyone have any idea where i have gone wrong with this?

Any advice and input would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: It looks right to me up to the WHERE clause.  If you just run that top part, i.e. no WHERE clause, does the data come back?

Comment: @TetonSig Yes, it does produce data with the rest removed...

Comment: The MATCH AGAINST syntax seems to be for pattern matching which may be subtly messing things up and adding unneeded complexity.  Can you just use WHERE c.id = {$_SESSION['input']} or are you trying to match multiple values and this is just a simple example with only one?

Comment: @TetonSig This is simply a simple example with only only category. I intened to offer users the ability to select multiple categories at one time. The WHERE ... = ... Approach does work, but as you stated, i am aiming for something a little more complex. Thank you for your input in anycase, it is appreciated!

Comment: No problem.  What version of mysql?

Comment: @TetonSig v5.5.8 on WAMP

Comment: I think you should be able to use the following if your $_Session['input'] is comma delimited:  
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(c.id,$_Session['input']) > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see now that you're building the SQL dynamically.  If that's the case, then this should work:

```
SELECT i.id, name, price
    FROM items i
    INNER JOIN item_categories
        ON i.id = item_id
    INNER JOIN categories c
        ON category_id = c.id
    WHERE c.id
    IN ('{$_SESSION['input']}')
    ORDER BY name
```

Just make sure  '{$_SESSION['input']}' is comma delimited and be aware that this carries the risk of SQL injection because you're constructing the SQL on the fly.